# Search filter for SKU

Tags: magento2, search, sku

In search bar when I search with SKU at that time suggetion popup appears.

Please guide me how can I overwrite search auto suggetion popup with new filter about SKU search

Comment: Please provide more details and context of the question

Comment: When I search by SKU I am getting  more the one result and it should not be like that